# Integrated Webcam not working Macbook Pro 2015

Tags: video, 20.04, webcam, bug-reporting, macbook-pro

I have just updated my 2015 Macbook Pro from Ubuntu 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS. However, I am unable to get the integrated webcam working. All repos and software are up to date, however I get no picture when using cheese or google hangouts. I've attempted to search for a solution, however I have not found a viable fix for the newest Focal Fossa release.